# I use a background image in tableview's cell and I use shadowOpacity, but it's so low on scrolling. how to Tuning?

Tags: ios, tableview

I use a background image in tableview's cell and I use shadowOpacity, but it's so low on scrolling. how to Tuning?

```
self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241 green:241 blue:241 alpha:1];
self.backgroundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.backgroundImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
self.backgroundImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
self.backgroundImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `shadowPath` property of the layer to a path that matches your rounded rectangle. Something like:

```
self.backgroundImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.backgroundImageView.bounds cornerRadius:10.0].CGPath;
```

Without this information the layer has to analyse its contents to decide where to render the shadow, which is what is hurting your scrolling performance.

Comment: thanks you! another question. I modify a imageview with bottom 2 cornor round code with:        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.photoImageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
        [maskPath addClip];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.photoImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;    I found it is   slow than make all corner round with code :   self.photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; why?

Comment: Masking with another layer is more complicated than adding a corner radius. You should ask a separate question.